# How can we delete multiple items from a list where the value is equal to 0?

Tags: python-3.x

```
edges=[
         ((1, 2): 9.433981132056603),
         ((1, 3): 18.973665961010276),
         ((1, 4): 0.0),
         ((1, 5): 82.87339742040264),
         ((1, 6): 29.966648127543394),
         ((1, 7): 0.0)
      ]
```

I have 5 items in the `edges` list.  How can I remove the keys `(1,4)` and `(1,7)`, where the value is 0?

Desired output:

```
edges [
         ((1, 2): 9.433981132056603),
         ((1, 3): 18.973665961010276),
         ((1, 5): 82.87339742040264),
         ((1, 6): 29.966648127543394)
      ]
```

Comment: I am sorry just now I sovled my problem

Answer (score 1):

I solved it with this code:

```
populated = filter(lambda c: c[1] >0, Edges)
print(list(populated))
```